# Why does descriptor redirection seem inconsistent?

Tags: bash

- Most of us know that to redirect STDERR to STDOUT we do `2>&1`
- We also know about FILE redirection using "`>`" and process redirection using "`|`"

What I always wondered about was about the combination of the above two

If you want to redirect both STDERR and STDOUT of **prog1** to **prog2** you place the `2>&1` prior to the `|prog2` pipe.  On the other hand, if you are redirecting STDERR and STDOUT of prog1 to a file (file.txt), the `2>&1` goes after the `> file.txt`.

So I know HOW to do it, I am just wondering WHY it is done like that.  To me it seems inconsistent, but I may be looking at it the wrong way

Thanks

Comment: I suggest feeling slightly less weird about it by using `&> file.txt` and `|& prog2` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are processed in order.

So if you do

```
progname 2>&1 1>out.txt
```

That diverts stderr **from the program** to the **current destination** of the program's stdout, which is the stdout stream **of the shell**, and diverts stdout of the program to out.txt.

if you do

```
progname 1>out.txt 2>&1
```

That diverts the stdout of the program to out.txt, then diverts the stderr **from the program** to the **current destination** of the program's stdout, which is out.txt.

Answer (score 1):

It helps if you don't think of a pipe as redirection. Using `2>&1`, you're redirecting stderr to stdout. Only stdout goes through a pipe. If you redirect stdout before a pipe, then nothing goes through.